# CSS Form Frameworks?

Tags: html, css

I have been looking at a couple html/css form frameworks like [Uni-Form](http://www.sprawsm.com/uni-form) and [Formy](http://code.google.com/p/formy-css-framework/). They provide easier management of html forms.  I was wondering if anyone knows similar ones. I am **not** looking for css grid frameworks nor Yahoo's YUI.

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "easier management" of forms. Are you looking for specific form field alignments? For consistent styling of form elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

blueprintCSS has a form plugin (I don't know if it can be used alone, I haven't tried to do that). http://www.blueprintcss.org/

http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/forms.html

Answer (score 2):

[Baseline CSS](http://baselinecss.com/form.html) also has a form system. I haven't personally used it.

Answer (score 1):

- [Formalize](http://formalize.me/)
- [Uniform](http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/) (different from Uni-Form)

Answer (score 1):

just tried formy and uniform.. 
i want something styled a bit simpler, just to look clean so i can do the rest..

[Formalize](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CC8QFjAD&url=http://formalize.me/&ei=Y3N7TZryKpCDhQfrja26Bw&usg=AFQjCNGWIVq7KXMTRlKTftvQZ_1weJseGA) is another one, quite simple, worth a look.. looked at uniform and [jformer](http://www.jformer.com/) and they're both too comprehensive, if that could be used as a reason to ignore them

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Tacit](https://yegor256.github.io/tacit/).

It's a "class-less" CSS framework were you only need a single `<link>` statement in your HTML and the web page will have a complete look. In particular, for forms, you get a more finished appearance out of the box, just by including the CSS file, and you don't need to attribute specific classes to your form elements. It also guarantees your form will work visually fine both in Desktop and in Mobile.

You can get an overall idea from the [demo page](http://yegor256.github.io/tacit/).

Here are also a few examples of pages that use Tacit, and the only work put into was including the CSS file: http://filfreire.com/, http://www.jare.io/, https://socatar.com/,

Answer (score 0):

I think uniform is the best solution for forms. 
Html is good and understandable, it has a bunch of tricky form examples solved very nicely ad it pays attention to usability much more than other frameworks.

Other seem to insist more on a vertical typographic rythm than common sense and usability. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also: Formy http://code.google.com/p/formy-css-framework/

Answer (score 0):

I have developer a single class CSS framework just for forms. The class "form" can be added to any form input to style it properly. You can see the examples on the documentation: https://form.js.org

Here an example of mailing list form:

```css
form {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@codolog/form@1.0.0/dist/form.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="email" class="form" placeholder="Enter your email">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="form full">Subscribe</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<form>
```